# Error: Can't assign Value of type '[SomeObject]' to type '[NSMutableArray]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have been trying to assign an Swift type of array to Objective-C type of array because i'm trying to use both Objective-C and Swift Class in my project.
In my swift class, I have declared an array `var musicEntities = [MusicEntity]()`
. When i try to assign to implement the following code:

```
let musicVC: MusicViewController = MusicViewController.sharedInstance()
musicVC.musicEntities = musicEntities // line2
```

In Line 2 i get the following error:

```
Can't assign Value of type '[SomeObject]' to type '[NSMutableArray]'
```

I know casting can help me to solve the problem.I have tried to find out specific answer in Stack Overflow but i didn't get any specific answer which might solve my problem. I tried many ways to cast it to NSMutableCompatible but i get different kind of error when i try to cast.

How can i cast that [MusicEntity] array to NSMutableArray? I need specific answer regarding my problem.

Looking forward for the answer.Thanks.

Comment: cast from unrelated type always failed. did you received this compiler warning, didn't you?

Comment: I mentioned in my question what kind of error i get. Yeah, When i tried to Cast i got the error you mentioned.

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: How is `MusicEntity` defined? How is `musicVC.musicEntities` defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try calling `mutableCopy` on `musicEntities` after casting it as `NSArray` and then downcast the result of that to `NSMutableArray`:

```
musicVC.musicEntities = (musicEntities as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Comment: When i implement your code then i get worning message " Cast from '() -> AnyObject' to unrelated type 'NSMutableArray' always fails". What to do?

Comment: Sorry about that.  `mutableCopy` is a method call, so I added `()` to the above code.

Comment: I have removed the Square Bracket from your code. musicEntities itself is an Array so there is no need to put it in Array Index. It is now working fine after removing the Square Bracket.

Comment: OK great.  I'll update my answer to be consistent with your code.  That was my original answer, but then I added the `[]` because I thought you needed `[NSMutableArray]` and not just `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, but see my WARNING

```
import Foundation

class C {}
var nsArray = NSMutableArray()
nsArray.addObject(C())
var swiftArray = nsArray as AnyObject as! [C]
dump(swiftArray)
swiftArray.dynamicType // Array<C>.Type
/*
▿ 1 element
- [0]: C #0
*/

// oposite

class C1 {}
var arr = [C1()]
// WARNING, if C1 will be value type (aka struct C1{})
// the next sentence will crash you programm
var nsArray1 = arr as! NSMutableArray // compiler warning
dump(nsArray1)
/*
▿ 1 element
- [0]: C1 #0
*/
nsArray1.dynamicType // _SwiftDeferredNSArray.Type
```

so next line will crash

```
nsArray1.addObject(C1())
```

the best you can do is make a new NSMutableArray and fill it up

```
let newNsArray = NSMutableArray(array: arr)
newNsArray.addObject(C())
dump(newNsArray)
/*
▿ 2 elements
- [0]: C1 #0
- [1]: C #1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an `NSMutableArray` with your Swift array cleanly with no need to cast:

```
let objcArray = NSMutableArray(array: musicEntities)
```